# Can't change display resolution on a Lenovo G575

Tags: display, resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo G575 (64 bit).  I was using my computer with the 1366x768 display resolution. I changed the display resolution of my computer to the 800x600 yesterday, then I tried to return it back to 1366x768, but I couldn't. When I try to change resolution, it's getting dark and it crashes. Then nothing happens. So I need to restart to open my computer. I used many methods which is written on the net to return the resolution back, but all these methods didn't work :(

**NOTE:**

When I create new user, the resolution for new user automatically is setting to 1366x768 and I can use this user. But I need to use my own user account.

How can I solve the problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user account has a custom monitor setting. See if removing the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`, then logging back out and in helps.